# Phenomenon that causes music to sound like it's being played at a different tempo than remembered?

Tags: terminology, memory, perception, music

Something I've noticed now and then is that I'll be listening to a song off my music player and it sounds like it's being played in a tempo faster or slower than I remember the song being. Is this a defined/known phenomenon, and if so what is it's name and cause/reason for happening?

Comment: _"Is this a defined/known phenomenon"_ A broken mp3 player? :) P.s.: This is on-topic here, but the question will be received better if you try googling for a bit and incorporate those findings in it.

Comment: @Steven: Heh, pretty sure it isn't that :P I've observed it over the years with several different ones. I tried googling some but the only thing I could find that was remotely related was something on music, memory, and how the brain stores absolute features of experienced events.

Comment: [_"music tempo perception memory"_](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=667&q=music+temp+perception&btnG=Google+Search&oq=comining+flex+and+flash&aq=f&aqi=g-jl1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=417l5113l0l5278l27l21l3l0l0l0l255l2226l8.8.1l17#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=music+tempo+perception+memory&oq=music+tempo+perception+memory&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...12614.13297.1.13493.7.7.0.0.0.0.64.414.7.7.0...0.0.dLLQTuVtdU8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=356e729b7a15c7f0&biw=1366&bih=667) is turning up some interesting links for me.

Comment: It is always better to explain what you know about the process already in your question, and if you don't know anything about it then do a little bit of [initial research](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/66/29) to better frame your question.

Answer (score 10):

[Vitouch et. al (2006)](http://www.marcocosta.it/icmpc2006/pdfs/330.pdf) observed that *"visual tempo significantly influenced 
the retrieved music tempo."*.

> Music is known to potentially affect the perception of visual  scenes
>   (e. g., Vitouch, 2001), as proficiently demonstrated  in the movies.
>   But do films also influence the perception of  music? This study
>   investigates cross-modal influences in  perception, taking influences
>   of “visual tempo” on  perceived/retrieved music tempo as a model.

They conclude:

> Both studies demonstrate clear crossover effects: There is  not just
>   “musical driving” of film scenes, but also “visual  driving” of music
>   perception. Results hint to holistic memory representations of
>   audio-visual material.

---

On the other hand, an older paper by [Levitin and Cook (1996)](http://cogprints.org/644/1/tempo.htm) observes that long term memory for music *can* preserve the absolute tempo, even by non-trained musicians. They do not investigate the influence of visual stimuli as in the previous paper.

> We report evidence that long term memory retains  absolute (accurate)
>   features of perceptual events. Specifically, we  show that memory for
>   music seems to preserve the absolute tempo  of the musical
>   performance. In Experiment 1, 46 subjects sang  popular songs from
>   memory, and their tempos were compared to  recorded versions of the
>   songs. Seventy-two of the subjects came within  8% of the actual tempo
>   on two consecutive trials (using different  songs), demonstrating
>   accuracy near the perceptual threshold (JND)  for tempo. In Experiment
>   2, a control experiment, we found that  folk songs lacking a tempo
>   standard generally have a large variability in tempo; this counters
>   arguments that memory for the  tempo of remembered songs is driven by
>   articulatory constraints.  The relevance of the current findings to
>   theories of perceptual  memory and memory for music are discussed.

<sub>Oliver Vitouch, Sandra Sovdat, Norman Höller (2006) [Audio-vision: Visual input drives perceived music tempo.](http://www.marcocosta.it/icmpc2006/pdfs/330.pdf) 9th International Conference on Music Perception and Cognition

Levitin, D. J. & Cook, Perry R.(1996) [Memory for musical tempo: Additional evidence that auditory memory is absolute.](http://cogprints.org/644/1/tempo.htm) Perception & Psychophysics, 58, pp. 927-935.</sub>

Comment: Also an interesting paper: Sabine Strauß & Oliver Vitouch (2009) [Adaptive memory representations of musical tempo and pitch](https://jyx.jyu.fi/dspace/bitstream/handle/123456789/20932/urn_nbn_fi_jyu-2009411324.pdf?sequence=1)